# Using stat() and wordexp() to display executable and hidden files in C

Tags: c

I am fairly new to Linux C Programming and need a little help displaying executable and hidden files using the stat and wordexp functions. ANy help is appreciated. Here is what i have so far:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    char fileName[60];

    char *pos;

    wordexp_t p;

    char **w;

    int i;

    struct stat st;

    fprintf(stdout,"Enter file name: ");
    fgets(fileName,sizeof(fileName),stdin);

    if((pos=rindex(fileName,'\n'))==(fileName+strlen(fileName)-1))
        *pos='\0';

    wordexp(fileName,&p,0);
    w = p.we_wordv;

    for(i = 0; i < p.we_wordc; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",w[i]);
        wordfree(&p);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, hidden file begins with dot, so you need to check first character of filename. 
Executable files can be filtered by checking file mode (you can read more about it [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) - look for st_mode field of this structure).
Below simple application, which lists all hidden or executable files in current directory:

```
#include <dirent.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(void)
{
  DIR           *d;
  struct dirent *dir;
  struct stat buf;
  d = opendir(".");
  if (d)
    {
      while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
    {
      stat(dir->d_name, &buf);
      if ((strlen(dir->d_name) > && dir->d_name[0] == '.') || (buf.st_mode & S_IXGRP || buf.st_mode & S_IXUSR || buf.st_mode & S_IXOTH)
        printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
    }

      closedir(d);
    }

  return(0);
}
```

You should also remember about two things:

- directories usually have executable permissions
- there are two special directories in linux: '.' and '..' 
  But I don't know whether you're going to filter it or not.